# I want to get the sum of data from array of the json object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the json data in array.

```
    var obj = [
        {
            student_data:{
                name: 'brj',
                id: '123',
                marks:[{'hi': 12, 'mt': 20, 'en': 20}]
            }
        },
        {
            student_data:{
                name: 'anand',
                id: '124',
                marks:[{'hi': 12, 'mt': 20, 'en': 20}]
            }
    
        }
    ]
```

here I want to add the marks and display the total, but i cant get it right because I'm unable to get the addition, here is the solution i tried.

```
    var i = 0;
    var t = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i<obj.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j<obj[i].student_data.marks[0].length; j++){
            t += obj[i].student_data.marks[0];
            //console.log(obj[i].student_data.marks[0])
            //console.log(t);
    
        };
        
    }
```

Expected output should be,

`{ '123':{ name: 'bji', total_marks: 52 } }, { '124':{ name: 'anand', total_marks: 52 } }`

Comment: You have to loop through `Object.values(obj[o].student_data.marks[0])`

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Expected result should be.

Comment: {
            '123':{
                name: 'bji',
                
                total_marks: 52
            }
        },
        {
            '124':{
                name: 'anand',
                
                total_marks: 52
            }
    
        }

Answer (score 1):

`obj[i].student_data.marks[0]` is an object, you can't add it to a number.

You need to iterate through its values, which can be done using `Object.values()`.

```js
var obj = [{
    student_data: {
      name: 'brj',
      id: '123',
      marks: [{
        'hi': 12,
        'mt': 20,
        'en': 20
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    student_data: {
      name: 'anand',
      id: '124',
      marks: [{
        'hi': 12,
        'mt': 20,
        'en': 20
      }]
    }
  }
];

var t = 0;
obj.forEach(o => o.student_data.marks.forEach(marks =>
  Object.values(marks).forEach(mark => t += mark)));
console.log(t);
```

Comment: thanks and how do i replace student data with their repective ids.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. This is totalling the marks of all students, not doing a per-student total.

Comment: i mean to say in our data there is a object name student_data i want to replace student_data with their respective ids.

Comment: example: student_data: {
      name: 'brj',
      id: '123',
      marks: [{
        'hi': 12,
        'mt': 20,
        'en': 20
      }     here student_data should be changed to '123' as it has id 123, it should look like, { '123':{ name: 'bji', total_marks: 52 } }

Comment: I think he means he wants the 'student_data' key to be replaced with the numerical value of the 'student_data' 'id' value. So the first one would change from 'student_data' to '123'

Comment: @Somesh That's a completely different question.

Comment: yes correct. student_data name should be replaced with "id"

Comment: yes i know sorry for the inconvenience, but is there any way i would be able to do this.

Comment: Yes, of course there is. `o[student_data.id] = what you want`

Comment: I'll leave doing `what you want` as your own exercise, I'm not going to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over the appropriate arrays:

```js
var obj = [{
    student_data: {
      name: 'brj',
      id: '123',
      marks: [{
        'hi': 12,
        'mt': 20,
        'en': 20
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    student_data: {
      name: 'anand',
      id: '124',
      marks: [{
        'hi': 12,
        'mt': 20,
        'en': 20
      }]
    }

  }
]
var sum = 0;
obj.forEach(e => e.student_data.marks.forEach(f => Object.keys(f).forEach(g => sum += f[g])));
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the two above are more efficient, you may wish to see it presented similar to your current code. Given your desired output:

```
var total = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
    obj[i].student_data["total_marks"] = 0;
    for(var k in obj[i].student_data.marks[0]){
        obj[i].student_data["total_marks"] += obj[i].student_data.marks[0][k];
    };    
}
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea?lq=1